# Google Tag Manager: _event equals gtm.js condition not satisfied/evaluated after login event in Next.JS application

Tags: authentication, next.js, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

Good day guys!

I need some help regarding the following: I use the following snippet to initialise the Google Tag Manager in my Next.JS application.

**_app.js**

```
<Script id={"data-layer-initialization"} strategy={"afterInteractive"}>
         {`window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []`}
</Script>
<Script id="google-tag-manager" strategy="afterInteractive">
                {`(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','${GMT_XXXXX}');`}
</Script>
```

**_document.js**

```
<noscript
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `<iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=${GMT_ID2}"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>`,
            }}
          />
```

I need to push some data layer information regarding the user details (e.g. id) when he has logged in and for this reason i am using the **react-gtm-module**. I am initialising basically the tag manager using the related gtmId, passing into the dataLayer object the info needed.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    TagManager.initialize({
      gtmId: GMT_ID2,
      dataLayer: {
        event: "login",
        authenticationMethod: 'email',
        userId: userId,
      },
    });
  }, [userId]);
};
```

From the GTM side, I have turned the information (user ID) into a GTM variable (data layer variable) and then insert the user ID variable in the GA4 configuration tag. When testing into the GTM preview mode, I sign-in but the container loaded after the login event does NOT fire the GA4 configuration tag (not evaluating any tags at all).

What am i missing?

I was expecting the GA4 configuration tag to be fired by the container loaded but nothing happened. In fact, no tags were evaluated at all.